# Differences in "prose" and "dot notation" when invoking a method with (explicit) implicit parameters

Tags: scala, syntax, parameter-passing

I'm not a Scala expert, and I'm confused about the syntax of calling a method with an implicit parameter.

Here's my situation:

I have a Spark RDD like this:

```
val myData: RDD[Array[String]] = ...
```

and have defined an Ordering for it:

```
object MyOrdering extends Ordering[Array[String]] = ...
```

I want to filter this RDD and take the top n entries in the RDD according to my Ordering.  A Spark RDD has a method for taking the top n entries with this signature:

```
def top(num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Array[T]
```

Initially I tried this code

```
myData filter { D =>
  D(9) == "yes"
} top(50)(MyOrdering)
```

Which fails with this error:

```
error: Int(50) does not take parameters
    } top(50)(MyOrdering)
```

However, this code works:

```
myData.filter(D => D(9) == "yes").top(50)(MyOrdering)
```

To my beginner's eye, the failing code sample and the working code sample look to be specifying equivalent logic.  Am I wrong here? Am I actually doing something different in the two code samples?  Or is this an issue with how the Scala compiler parses the code?

Comment: The error indicates the first is parsed similarly to `(myData filter { D =>  D(9) == "yes" } top)(50(MyOrdering))`, where the `(50)` is not taken as a method parameter itself. The reported error can be minimally reproduced with `50("Hello!")`, for instance. That is, even without the implicit (additional parameter list), how does it parse? Or is it only this addition that changes the syntax behavior?

Comment: Without the implicit parameter list it works fine, for instance this works:

`implicit val myOrd: Ordering[Array[String]] = MyOrdering`
`myData filter { D => 
  D(9) == "yes"
} top(50)`

Comment: A simpler example without spark would be `List(1, 2, 3, 4) filter(_ > 2) sortBy(_ * -1)(scala.math.Ordering.Int)`

Comment: @user2864740 is correct, and this can be solved if you wrap the entire expression except for the implicit in a parens and force the compiler to realize the operator precedence

Answer (score 1):

You can only replace the dot `.` with a space for method invocation when the method is arity-1 (1 parameter list) or arity-0 (no parameter lists).  For example, this fails to compile:

```
class Foo {
    def baz(x: Int)(y: Int) = this
    def qux(x: Int) = this
}

(new Foo) baz(1)(1) //Does not compile
(new Foo).baz(1)(1) //Allowed
(new Foo) qux(1) //Allowed, since qux is arity-1
(new Foo).qux(1) //Also allowed, of course
```

When the the last parameter list is `implicit` the compiler can treat a method with `n` parameter lists as if it has arity `n-1` if the method is being invoked with an `implicit` argument:

```
class Foo {
    def baz(x: Int)(implicit y: Int) = this
}

implicit val y: Int = 1
(new Foo) baz(1) //Allowed
(new Foo).baz(1) //Also fine
(new Foo) baz(1)(2) //Still not allowed
(new Foo).baz(1)(2) //Still allowed
```

Read more about the rules for method invocation in [the style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html).